# Run Python Program After PHP

Tags: python, php

I'm trying to make a program where PHP writes something into a notepad file, and then python will read it afterwards.

Here is my sample code in PHP:

```
    <?php
        $myFile = fopen('mynotepadfile.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($myFile, 'Hello, how are you?');
        fclose($myFile);
        //I'm going to change the code in a way where the client can input the message to be written in the txt file.
    ?>
```

And here is my python file:

```
    txt_file = 'mynotepadfile.txt'
    f = open(txt_file, 'r')
    
    print(f.read())
    
    f.close()
```

Now they can interact with the same txt file. My problem, however, is that the python file must start in itself after the client has written a message on the txt file through PHP. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Check out `file_put_contents()`, btw.

Comment: BTW: You either tell the waiting Python program to process the file now or you start it yourself to immediately process the file. One question is then "how to do IPC?" and the other "how to start a program?". Use those search terms to locate an approach.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt IPC is new to me. Is it essential for me to know that to attain my goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply execute python file in the end of the php file execution.

```
<?php 

txt_file = 'mynotepadfile.txt'
f = open(txt_file, 'r')
    
print(f.read())
f.close()

$command = escapeshellcmd('/python/file/path.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
?>
```

I believe this could be done much easily from the place of the php file execution as well.

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve my problem, sir. The PHP doesn't echo the output.

Comment: Amended. Actually you do not need to as per your requirement.Can you check back.

Comment: Should it supposedly execute the python program? I tried it again, I reviewed my code. All I did was add escapeshellcmd and shell_exec. It changes the contents of the txt file, but it does not execute my python file.

Comment: I'm using Windows by the way

Comment: Concerning that the "PHP doesn't echo the output", there is nothing in your question that has that requirement.